# How to show related list on Classic Page Layout and not on Lightning Page?

Tags: lightning, page-layout, lightning-record-page

We are using both Classic and Lightning and I am trying to account for both.

I had a requirement to Design a Lightning Record Page for lightning where I created a LWC that is used in place of a Related List(there was logic that needed to be on the related list to show what displays - The related List is Price Book Entries and cannot be modified). I removed the Price Book Entries related list from the page layout. This works as planned in Lightning however we still want to see the original related list in classic.

I see that the Lightning Record Page is assign by Profile's, Page Layouts and Record Types. How can I set this up where as in Lightning they see one Page Layout but in Classic they see another? Should I be using Record Types to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that comes to my mind and which is pretty easy to implement is to get rid of `Related Lists` default component on Lightning Page and to add every desired related list in a form of `Related List - Single`. That way you can keep related lists defined for Page Layout and use whatever related list you want on your Lightning Page.

[image]

Comment: That is brilliant.Works like a charm